# Typescript: Check that type is not any

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Let's say i have a type `AnyWidget` that is the union of a lot of different types.
`type AnyWidget = Button | Label | HeaderComponent | ...`
Since this type will be extended by whoever adds a widget i want to prevent it from accidentally becoming `any` just because someone forgot to properly type a widget.

So I would like to add a check that this type is not `any`. Any ideas how I would be able to do that?

Some more context:

- `no-implicit-any` is unfortunately set to false in this project
- As Fabian Lauer already pointed out a unit test is not possible in this case. So I am looking for other ideas. Such as custom lint rules or a different type definition to achieve this goal.
- A superclass is not useful in this case since the type is being used to generate a json schema out of it.

Comment: Why not define a superclass/interface `Widget`, instead of making it a union?

Comment: I am using this type to generate a json schema out of it. So a  superclass wont do in this case.

Comment: *i want to prevent it from accidentally becoming any just because someone forgot to properly type a widget.* - isn't it what noImplicitAny is for? Otherwise explicit `any` can hardly be qualified as "forgot" and needs to be fought with `no-any` linter rule. There are several helper libs, search GH for "typescript type check" and "typescript assert". It's unnecessary that tests will need or be compatible with Jest, especially if tests are executed on compilation time with `tsc --noEmit`. Not sure which one can be helpful for `any` problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Unit testing (e.g. with jest as you suggest) happens at runtime, but types in TypeScript only exist at compile time. This means you cannot test types using unit tests.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. do you know of any other ways to verify types? like a linter rule or compile hint?

Comment: This maybe? https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-any/ :)